# How to select child element in Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to check the textContent of a div that is a child of the component for which I'm writing the unit tests.

The HTML looks like

```html
<div 
    [ngClass]="containerClasses"
    *ngIf="showTooltip">

    <div [ngClass]="arrowClasses"></div>
    
    <div  class="label" id="label"> {{ label }} </div> 
</div>
```

I want to check the textContent of the div with class="label".

I have tried approaches given on the internet and even on angular's website but they all return only null. Here's a snippet of how I tried it.

```js
it('should have a label with max 255 chars', () => {
    // approach 1
     const labelElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.label'); // null

    // approach 2
    const labelElement2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.label')); // null

    // approach 3
    const labelElement3 = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#label'); // null

    // approach 4
    const labelElement4 = fixture.debugElement.query((de)=>{return de.nativeElement.id==="label"}); // null
  })
```

All of these approaches are said to be valid approaches online. But all of them return null when I do console.log or try to access the textContent property.

What should I do?

Comment: I think its better to use the respected tag that the testing library provides, for example on Cypress, its `data-cy`

Comment: Can you check your *ngIf, the unit test may not be finding the label element since the parent is hidden. Try removing the ngif for once and test.

Comment: why aren't you using the innerText property?

Comment: UPDATE: innerText also wasn't working. I removed the ngIf and now I can access the children. I had to set the showTooltip = true and do fixture.detectChanges() and it worked. But now I'am stuck on not being able to access the css lol.